# why dishwashers do not use inox basket?

Tags: dishwasher

Why dishwashers do not use inox baskets for racks as they use it for dishwasher walls?
I guess price, but why can't I find some online ? Even for professionals.
I'd rather change the rusty basket for an inox one that change the working dishwasher...
I mean, planned obsolescence is the first reason I would think of but there could be a good reason for not using it...

Comment: The plastic basket in my dishwasher lasted for more than 10 years - probably because I don't **drop** the cutlery in it...

Comment: I've never seen a dishwasher that doesn't use a plastic basket.

Comment: Unless you have a very obscure dishwasher, you can likely buy a replacement basket for a fraction of the price of a new dishwasher.

Comment: `Why dishwashers do not use inox baskets?` ... that is not an answerable question ... downvote

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly get (commercial) dishwashers with stainless steel baskets, but they cost a factor of 5-6X what a typical home unit goes for. Upside - much faster cycle times. Then again, many of those use completely plastic (no wire core to rust) baskets, of different sorts to wash different things.

As for replacement baskets for an existing home machine, you'd be looking at custom work or the same thing it came with if even available (appliance parts often are not available a short time after manufacture of that model ends, particularly large and specific ones like that.) You'd also increase the odds of chipping plates (**coated wire or a plastic basket are easier on glass/ceramics than hard wire.**) That would be the non-obsolescence reason.

Recoating may be an option.

The coated wire basket in my home-grade dishwasher has been fine for several decades of home use, no rust. Its walls are plastic, not stainless. Are you running sharp things against the coated wire?